# Phonegap best practice to save data over the 5mb limit

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, sqlite, cordova

I'm developing a business app and need to save away more than 5mb in total. For instance I started using localStorage worked just fine, till I reached the good old 5mb limit.

Whats' the best practice at the moment to solve this problem ?

- Can I extend the limit ?
- Is there another database key/value system because I prefer, I now I'm alone on this. But I'm used to it since I started heavy JSON using on node.js applications.
- Can I use the native SQLite database ?

btw. my solution should work on iOS, Android and sadly also on WP8.

Cheers Marvin

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop PhoneGap app with database storage > 5MB to be distributed on almost all platforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441339/how-to-develop-phonegap-app-with-database-storage-5mb-to-be-distributed-on-alm)

Comment: Thanks for your link, but I'm still not sure if sqlite has a limit and is it working on android and wp8 too ? why isn't theire a documentation from phonegap ? although there is a kind of storage documentation for version 2.1.0 but for my version 3.4.0 you only get a little description for LocalStorage, WebSql, IndexedDB and they are all limited in size if I understood it the right way..

Comment: SQLite has no limits; the 5 GB limit is implemented by PhoneGap.

Comment: Do you mean 5 gb or mb ?

Comment: @marvin have a look on my answer pls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this will help you.

Use SQLitePlugin , anybody can read about it from http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.triarc.sqliteplugin

just add this plugin to your project simply like

```
cordova plugin add com.triarc.sqliteplugin
```

if previously you are using SQL API In your project, you need not to worry just replace this thing

**SQL API**

```
var db = window.openDatabase("my_db", "1.0", "MY DB", 200000);
```

**SQLitePlugin**

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my_db"});
```

and use all other code  as it is.

Comment: Can't validate your answer atm because this project is outdated a long time ago. But thanks anyway, maybe it helps some further fellows.