# phonegap database-which is the correct method?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to implement an application in **Phonegap Android**. For the past two days,I am scouting for a proper way of accessing the database and retrieving it from the same.I did not find an answer to my questions

I have learnt that Phonegap does not support SQLLITE but supports the W3C Web SQL Database Specification and W3C Web Storage.

At the same  time I noticed few plugins for Phonegap 1.5..which does not exist now. At the same time i found that W3c database provides a limited storage of 5MB for **iOS**.

I found this SQL Plugin for Phonegap Android  [**PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-Android**](https://github.com/brodyspark/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-Android)  Is it advicable to use this or any other method. Please,guide me.

So,if you have any sort of example of accessing the database that can be followed please share it.

Answer (score 1):

I've already answered a similar question here ::

[Phonegap Offline Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005042/phonegap-offline-database/15811728)

It outlines the steps with all the detail you could need. I'm reposting the answer here.

**1. LocalStorage ::**

Check for localStorage

```
function supports_html5_storage() {
  try {
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Set an item into LocalStorage

```
localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);
```

or

```
localStorage["bar"] = foo;
```

Get an item from LocalStorage

```
var foo = localStorage.getItem("bar");
```

or

```
var foo = localStorage["bar"];
```

**2. SQLite Database (more convenient, more persistive)**

Set up your DB

```
var shortName = 'BHCAppDB'; 
var version = '1.0'; 
var displayName = 'BHCAppDB'; 
var maxSize = 65535; 
if (!window.openDatabase){ 
     alert('!! Databases are not supported in this Device !! \n\n We are sorry for the inconvenience and are currently working on a version that will work on your phone'); 
}
db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);
createAllTables(db);
```

Create your Tables

```
function createAllTables(db){
    db.transaction(function(transaction){
        transaction.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Profile(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT, gender TEXT,age INTEGER)");
}
```

Execute an SQL Query

```
transaction(function(transaction){
        var rowCount = 'SELECT * FROM Profile';
        transaction.executeSql(rowCount,[],function(transaction,result){
            if(result.rows.length == 0){
                var sqlString = 'INSERT INTO Profile (name,gender,age) VALUES("自己","Female",18)';
                transaction.executeSql(sqlString);

            }
        });
    });
```

**3. Native Storage on all devices**

This is the best part of Phonegap. You can call a native plugin class on all the devices using the Phonegap plugin call. During the call, you can pass parameters to the class, and the native class can store your data in the OS itself.

For example :: in iOS, you create a plugin .h & .m class and register it with the Cordova.plist file. Once that's done, you need to send a call to the class from JavaScript using Phonegap. Once the parameters have been received using NSDictionary or any other NSArray type, you can call a CoreData class to store UNLIMITED amounts of data. You'll never run out of memory .

This can be done in a similar fashion for all the rest of the OS's also :)

For Encryption try the following :: SQLCipher

Here is some additional information on working with an existing SQLite database. In this example encrypted.db is that brand new database you create and pragma.

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'encrypted.db' AS encrypted KEY 'secret'; -- create a new encrypted database
CREATE TABLE encrypted.t1(a,b); -- recreate the schema in the new database (you can inspect all objects using SELECT * FROM sqlite_master)
INSERT INTO encrypted.t1 SELECT * FROM t1; -- copy data from the existing tables to the new tables in the encrypted database
DETACH DATABASE encrypted;
```