# Phonegap: how to store a lot of data in a SQL-like mode?

Tags: cordova

I've just seen that phonegap 3.4 no longer provide API doc for storage.

Which is the raccomended way now?
I need some relational table support in my app, because I need some complicated data managment and SQL is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/the_storage_api_is_gone_start_on_3_2_and_delete_start_on_3_4):

> We have dropped support for platforms that needed a PhoneGap
>   implementation of Storage API and all supported currently devices can
>   **use the WebView implementation provided by W3C**.
>
> You can find samples as before at this [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage).
>
> Please as explained in the Storage API instruction, **use WebSQL and**
>   **IndexedDB** for the respective platforms as listed in our Storage API
>   guide.

See [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/) for examples using IndexedDB.

See [here](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/) for examples using WebSQL.

Whichever client side storage you use, make sure it is supported on the devices you're targeting by checking [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/).

Comment: Just be careful with IndexedDB as it is only currently supported on Windows Phone 8 and BlackBerry 10

Comment: But ... W3C discontinued working on WebSQL .. so .. now?

Comment: @realtebo More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005042/phonegap-offline-database/15811728)